# How to generate MySQL table from Go struct

Tags: mysql, go

I'm creating a CRUD program using Go and I have quite a big struct with over 70 fields that I want to add to a MySQL database.

I was wondering if there's a way to automatically map the struct into my database so I wouldn't have to create the table manually and it would just copy my struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a way to totally automate that process, but atleast you can create them using tags and only a little bit of code.

### Workarround example:

There are some github projects in the wild, which help you to achieve this.

For example [structable](https://github.com/Masterminds/structable)

You'd have to add tags to your structs members.

Example from github:

```
type Stool struct {
  Id         int    `stbl:"id, PRIMARY_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT"`
  Legs   int    `stbl:"number_of_legs"`
  Material string `stbl:"material"`
  Ignored  string // will not be stored. No tag.
}
```

When you have that part, you can create the table like in the following example (also from the github page)

```
stool := new(Stool)
stool.Material = "Wood"
db := getDb() // Get a sql.Db. You're on  the hook to do this part.

// Create a new structable.Recorder and tell it to
// bind the given struct as a row in the given table.
r := structable.New(db, "mysql").Bind("test_table", stool)

// This will insert the stool into the test_table.
err := r.Insert()
```

Answer (score 2):

try [gen-model](https://github.com/DaoYoung/gen-model)

```
go get -u github.com/DaoYoung/gen-model
gen-model init # then set value in .gen-model.yaml
gen-model create
```

done

Answer (score 0):

This project made by me: https://github.com/sunary/sqlize

- allow create migrate from struct
- detect differ between struct and existence sql